# How to run Selenium tests with single click or single command?

Tags: java, selenium, jar, selenium-webdriver, executable-jar

I'm writing Selenium tests using Java + Maven + Selenium WebDriver. Our customer wants these tests in such a way that they can run tests easily without much technical stuff needed.

I've all my tests under `src\test\java` folder. Is there any way where I can give jar file or so to the customer and they can run tests by simply clicking on it or by hitting some command on the command line.

Please point me to documentation or video using which I can achieve this.

Comment: through your command line give goal as `package`. This will create a jar file of your test-project in `target` folder. Do remember to create a main class to invoke executions.

Comment: Also, you have consider reporting functionality; it is meaningless unless you'll provide some output to customer about test results.

Comment: @VivekSingh, what you said, I couldn't grasp much. Can you please point me to link where I can find all detailed steps that you mentioned above?

Answer (score 2):

I've been using Visual Studio to write my Selenium tests in C#. I am able to build my project to a console application in Visual Studio that contains the required files like the Chrome webdriver. It can be run from this single application file with one click. The console then prints out if the test is a success or if their are any exceptions. You should also be able to integrate a headless browser like selenium has on their site. This would allow the test to be run with one click and no browser will pop up while the tests are running.This is all the experience I have and it has worked well for me. Hope that this information can help a little.